# Trying to run Pi-hole as a DHCP server in Docker but lighttpd service conflicts on port 80 with OctoPrint

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, dhcp-server, lighttpd, pihole

I need help setting up Pi-Hole in Docker running alongside OctoPrint in Docker. I did the initial setup for Pi-Hole in Docker:

1. Pulled the Pi-Hole container
2. Ran the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# https://github.com/pi-hole/docker-pi-hole/blob/master/README.md

PIHOLE_BASE="${PIHOLE_BASE:-$(pwd)}"
[[ -d "$PIHOLE_BASE" ]] || mkdir -p "$PIHOLE_BASE" || { echo "Couldn't create storage directory>

# Note: FTLCONF_LOCAL_IPV4 should be replaced with your external ip.
docker run -d \
    --name pihole \
    -p 53:53/tcp -p 53:53/udp \
    -p 8000:8000 \
    -e TZ="America/Chicago" \
    -v "${PIHOLE_BASE}/etc-pihole:/etc/pihole" \
    -v "${PIHOLE_BASE}/etc-dnsmasq.d:/etc/dnsmasq.d" \
    --dns=127.0.0.1 --dns=1.1.1.1 \
    --net=host \
    --restart=unless-stopped \
    --hostname pi.hole \
    -e VIRTUAL_HOST="pi.hole" \
    -e PROXY_LOCATION="pi.hole" \
    -e FTLCONF_LOCAL_IPV4="216.212.8.163" \
    pihole/pihole:latest

printf 'Starting up pihole container '
for i in $(seq 1 20); do
    if [ "$(docker inspect -f "{{.State.Health.Status}}" pihole)" == "healthy" ] ; then
        printf ' OK'
        echo -e "\n$(docker logs pihole 2> /dev/null | grep 'password:') for your pi-hole: http>        exit 0
    else
        sleep 3
        printf '.'
    fi

    if [ $i -eq 20 ] ; then
        echo -e "\nTimed out waiting for Pi-hole start, consult your container logs for more in>        exit 1
    fi
done;
```

When I run the bash script, it times out so I check the logs to see what might be the problem:

```
2024-01-03 15:08:28: network.c.369) can't bind to socket: 0.0.0.0:80: Address already in use
Stopping lighttpd
lighttpd: no process found
```

It says that lighttpd conflicts with another service on port 80, which would be OctoPrint as I've already verified this. So, I change the port that lighttpd is listening on to port 8000 by editing /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf to the following (as well as restart the lighttpd service):

```
server.modules = (
        "mod_indexfile",
        "mod_access",
        "mod_alias",
        "mod_redirect",
)

server.document-root        = "/var/www/html"
server.upload-dirs          = ( "/var/cache/lighttpd/uploads" )
server.errorlog             = "/var/log/lighttpd/error.log"
server.pid-file             = "/run/lighttpd.pid"
server.username             = "www-data"
server.groupname            = "www-data"
server.port                 = 8000

# features
#https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Server_feature-flagsDetails
server.feature-flags       += ("server.h2proto" => "enable")
server.feature-flags       += ("server.h2c"     => "enable")
server.feature-flags       += ("server.graceful-shutdown-timeout" => 5)
#server.feature-flags       += ("server.graceful-restart-bg" => "enable")

# strict parsing and normalization of URL for consistency and security
# https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Server_http-parseoptsDetails
# (might need to explicitly set "url-path-2f-decode" = "disable"
#  if a specific application is encoding URLs inside url-path)
server.http-parseopts = (
  "header-strict"           => "enable",# default
  "host-strict"             => "enable",# default
  "host-normalize"          => "enable",# default
  "url-normalize-unreserved"=> "enable",# recommended highly
  "url-normalize-required"  => "enable",# recommended
  "url-ctrls-reject"        => "enable",# recommended
  "url-path-2f-decode"      => "enable",# recommended highly (unless breaks app)
 #"url-path-2f-reject"      => "enable",
  "url-path-dotseg-remove"  => "enable",# recommended highly (unless breaks app)
 #"url-path-dotseg-reject"  => "enable",
 #"url-query-20-plus"       => "enable",# consistency in query string
)

index-file.names            = ( "index.php", "index.html" )
url.access-deny             = ( "~", ".inc" )
static-file.exclude-extensions = ( ".php", ".pl", ".fcgi" )

# default listening port for IPv6 falls back to the IPv4 port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/use-ipv6.pl " + server.port
include_shell "/usr/share/lighttpd/create-mime.conf.pl"
include "/etc/lighttpd/conf-enabled/*.conf"

#server.compat-module-load   = "disable"
server.modules += (
        "mod_dirlisting",
        "mod_staticfile",
)
```

And I get the same EXACT error, down to the same port, being 80.

You also probably noticed that I made some minor changes to the bash script, I changed the port in the bash script to 8000:8000 as well as added `--net=host`

What could possibly be the issue here?

UPDATE:

I made a little progress. Slightly different error, it seems that nothing is conflicting on port 80 with it anymore. New output when running my startup script command `sudo ./pihole_startup.sh` is below:

```
gigoiy@multiserver:~ $ sudo ./pihole_startup.sh
WARNING: Localhost DNS setting (--dns=127.0.0.1) may fail in containers.
aa4cb71f5e1be1b14f4c4744fcb180ae27db68ee86463507ffcedfa071a6acd9
Starting up pihole container .......... OK
 for your pi-hole: http:///admin/
```

When I run the command `sudo docker container ls`:

```
gigoiy@multiserver:~ $ sudo docker container ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND      CREATED          STATUS                    PORTS                                               NAMES
750ebaa202b0   pihole/pihole:latest   "/s6-init"   47 seconds ago   Up 45 seconds (healthy)                                                       pihole
5527f2878f24   octoprint/octoprint    "/init"      54 minutes ago   Up 53 seconds             80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp, :::5000->5000/tcp   gigoiy_octoprint_1
```

Notice how there's no ip and port binded in the last column of the `ls` for the pi-hole container?

Now when I run `sudo docker logs pihole`:

```
2024-01-10 19:10:05: network.c.369) can't bind to socket: 216.212.8.163:80: Cannot assign requested address
Stopping lighttpd
lighttpd: no process found
2024-01-10 19:10:07: network.c.369) can't bind to socket: 216.212.8.163:80: Cannot assign requested address
Stopping lighttpd
lighttpd: no process found
2024-01-10 19:10:08: network.c.369) can't bind to socket: 216.212.8.163:80: Cannot assign requested address
Stopping lighttpd
lighttpd: no process found
  Pi-hole version is v5.17.3 (Latest: v5.17.3)
  web version is v5.21 (Latest: v5.21)
  FTL version is v5.24 (Latest: v5.24)
  Container tag is: 2024.01.0

2024-01-10 19:10:09: network.c.369) can't bind to socket: 216.212.8.163:80: Cannot assign requested address
Stopping lighttpd
lighttpd: no process found
2024-01-10 19:10:10: network.c.369) can't bind to socket: 216.212.8.163:80: Cannot assign requested address
Stopping lighttpd
```

Instead of saying "address already in use", it simply says "cannot assign requested address". Different error is progress!

I also discovered that I had some stray docker containers hiding using up that port which may have caused the previous issue. If you can see, it's also giving me the correct ip when throwing the error, being the host ip.

Here's the corrected bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# https://github.com/pi-hole/docker-pi-hole/blob/master/README.md

PIHOLE_BASE="${PIHOLE_BASE:-$(pwd)}"
[[ -d "$PIHOLE_BASE" ]] || mkdir -p "$PIHOLE_BASE" || { echo "Couldn't create storage directory: $PIHOLE_BASE"; exit 1; }

# Note: FTLCONF_LOCAL_IPV4 should be replaced with your external ip.
docker run -d \
    --name pihole \
    -e TZ="America/Chicago" \
    -e DHCP_ACTIVE=true \
    -v "${PIHOLE_BASE}/etc-pihole:/etc/pihole" \
    -v "${PIHOLE_BASE}/etc-dnsmasq.d:/etc/dnsmasq.d" \
    --dns=127.0.0.1 --dns=1.1.1.1 \
    --net=host \
    --restart=unless-stopped \
    --hostname pi.hole \
    -e VIRTUAL_HOST="pi.hole" \
    -e PROXY_LOCATION="pi.hole" \
    -e FTLCONF_LOCAL_IPV4="216.212.8.163" \
    pihole/pihole:latest

printf 'Starting up pihole container '
for i in $(seq 1 20); do
    if [ "$(docker inspect -f "{{.State.Health.Status}}" pihole)" == "healthy" ] ; then
        printf ' OK'
        echo -e "\n$(docker logs pihole 2> /dev/null | grep 'password:') for your pi-hole: http://${IP}/admin/"
        exit 0
    else
        sleep 3
        printf '.'
    fi

    if [ $i -eq 20 ] ; then
        echo -e "\nTimed out waiting for Pi-hole start, consult your container logs for more info (\`docker logs pihole\`)"
        exit 1
    fi
done;
```

I also think that lighttpd has no effect in my issues for too many reasons that I'm too lazy to type out, so take my word.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `--net=host`, you can port forward using the format `-p 8000:80/tcp` where 8000 is the external/host port, and 80 is just for that docker container.

Or if you need to stay in host mode: Change the lighttpd settings *inside* the docker container by using the docker environment variable `-e WEB_PORT=8000`, but note:

> This will break the 'webpage blocked' functionality of Pi-hole however it may help advanced setups like those running synology or --net=host docker argument.

https://github.com/pi-hole/docker-pi-hole/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I've made the proper port forwarding changes to the bash script and created a external.conf and still getting the same exact error down to the same ports being mentioned.

Comment: @Gigoiy Ah, I missed that you added `--net=host`, which makes the docker `-p` parameter irrelevant. Why change the network mode? I mixed up which service was running inside the container - lighttpd will not check your config files, but they have environment variables to feed into Docker - updated my answer

Comment: I changed the network mode to host because it says in the documentation that it's best to run it in that mode if I'm using Pi-Hole as a DHCP server. Since my last reply, I tried your suggestion which was to use the WEB_PORT env variable and I've also tried using the bridged network mode and forwarded port 443 instead of port 80 in the bash script. I'm still getting the same error. It honestly might be easier to change the port that OctoPrint is listening on and will try that next.

Comment: @Gigoiy ah yeah for DHCP it's easier (though you'll need to open port 67:67/udp) . Can you clarify which things you tried at the same time? You would need to use `host` mode, remove the `-p 443:80`, add the env variable (you might need to quote it? like `WEB_PORT="8000"`), then restart the docker instance together. You should see a line like `Custom WEB_PORT set to 8000` in the docker startup debug output

Comment: I apologize for the late reply, but I easily switched the port that OctoPrint was running on. I'm not home at the moment so details may be light due to memory. Anyways, after I switched the port for OctoPrint, lighttpd was able to start and run on port 80 normally outside of docker, which is huge because lighttpd wasn't running at all before. But, despite this progress, I still get the same error when trying to run the bash script that starts the docker container, again down to the port number. I'll try what you recommend when I get home but I believe I already tried that.

Comment: Which log file is that error in? Octoprint or its webservice may still be controlling port 80 on the host. Or something *inside* the docker container is messing with that container's port 80. I think stuff like selinux can block apps from binding to ports, but the default Pi OS doesn't have that.

Comment: I made progress! Please see original post for the update. I'm running out of characters here lmao!

Comment: @Gigoiy are you sure that `216.212.8.163` is the IP of a LAN interface on the host and not the public IP of your router for example? It also looks like docker might still be stealing the host's port 80 for octoprint based on your `docker container ls` output, even if octoprint itself is only listening on 5000 now.